# Snowflake - Grouping with a "key change"

Tags: sql, grouping, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a problem I haven't found an answer myself or by research, although it should be something that is possible.

Imagine having the following data in a Snowflake table (exact column types shouldn't matter):

| ColumnA | ColumnB | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| SYSTEM | I | 02:01 |
| SYSTEM | I | 02:02 |
| SYSTEM | U | 02:03 |
| SYSTEM | U | 02:04 |
| SYSTEM | I | 02:05 |
| SYSTEM | U | 02:06 |

I want to aggregate the data such that I'll have 4 groups in my result set with min and max timestamp per group:

1. group: first two records with ColumnB = I (min = 02:01, max = 02:02)
2. group: next two records with ColumnB = U (min = 02:03, max = 02:04)
3. group: 5th record (min, max both = 02:05)
4. group: 6th record (min, max both = 02:06)

Note that there can be other values for columnA, and if so, they should be in their own groups, by the same principle.
Does anyone have an idea how to do this with some SELECT statement? GROUP BY obviously doesn't work since I can't separate groups 1 and 3 (and 2 and 4, resp.) that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a type of gaps-and-islands problem.  In this case, I think a difference of row numbers is the simplest way to address the problem:

```
select columnA, columnB, min(timestamp), max(timestamp)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by columnA order by timestamp) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by columnA, columnB order by timestamp) as seqnum_2
      from t
     ) t
group by columnA, columnB, (seqnum - seqnum_2);
```

Why this works is a little tricky to explain.  However, if you look at the results of the subquery you will see how the difference is constant for adjacent rows where `columnB` is the same.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will try it out!

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, with additional subgroup column:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *, LAG(ColumnB) OVER(PARTITION BY ColumnA ORDER BY timestamp) AS prevColumnB
  FROM tab
), cte2 AS (
  SELECT *, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN ColumnB = prevColumnB OR prevColumnB IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) 
    OVER(PARTITION BY ColumnA ORDER BY timestamp) as subgrp
  FROM cte
)
SELECT ColumnA, ColumnB, subgrp, MIN(timestamp) AS min_t, MAX(timestamp) AS max_t
FROM cte2
GROUP BY ColumnA, ColumnB, subgrp
ORDER BY ColumnA, subgrp;
```

How does it work:

```
+----------+----------+-----------+-------------+--------+
| ColumnA  | ColumnB  | timestamp | prevColumnB | subgrp |
+----------+----------+-----------+-------------+--------+
| SYSTEM   | I        | 02:01     | NULL        |      0 |
| SYSTEM   | I        | 02:02     | I           |      0 |
| SYSTEM   | U        | 02:03     | I           |      1 |
| SYSTEM   | U        | 02:04     | U           |      1 |
| SYSTEM   | I        | 02:05     | U           |      2 |
| SYSTEM   | U        | 02:06     | I           |      3 |
+----------+----------+-----------+-------------+--------+
```

By introducing `subgrp` column we could perform standard grouping.

---

Addendum:

The **[MATCH_RECOGNIZE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/match_recognize.html)** clause allows to achieve similar effect without using CTE.

```
SELECT *
FROM t
MATCH_RECOGNIZE  (
  PARTITION BY columnA
   ORDER BY timestamp
   MEASURES MATCH_NUMBER() AS grp_id
            --,CLASSIFIER() AS cls
            ,FIRST_VALUE(columnB) AS columnB
            ,FIRST_VALUE(timestamp) AS min_t
            ,LAST_VALUE(timestamp) AS max_t
  PATTERN (b* a)
  DEFINE a AS columnB != LEAD(columnB) OR LEAD(columnB) IS NULL
       ,b  AS columnB = LEAD(columnB)
) mr
ORDER BY columnA, grp_id;
```

Result:

```
COLUMNA GRP_ID  COLUMNB MIN_T   MAX_T
SYSTEM  1   I   02:01   02:02
SYSTEM  2   U   02:03   02:04
SYSTEM  3   I   02:05   02:05
SYSTEM  4   U   02:06   02:06
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will try it out!